# Why is a MediaStore file's parent not a directory?

Tags: mediastore, android-file

Some video files (*.mp4) were created with MediaStore and they work perfectly.
The Uri of a file is retrieved with ContentResolver query.

- Uri: `content://media/external/video/media/74`
- DISPLAY_NAME: `foo.mp4`

A file is created with the Uri as follows:

```
File file = new File(uri.getPath());
```

- file.getAbsolutePath(): `/external/video/media/74`
- file.getName(): `74`
- file.getParentFile(): `/external/video/media`
- file.getParentFile().isDirectory(): `false`
- file.getParentFile().list(): `null`

Could anyone shed some light on why file.getParentFile() (/external/video/media) is not a directory? Is there a way to get all the files and folders under "/external/video/media" without resorting to ContentResolver query?